# python pandas crosstab sumproduct square matrix

Tags: python, pandas

i'm looking for help creating a sub-dataframe from an existing dataframe using a sumproduct-like function. I want to convert this table, into a small sum product using the column headings:

```
    dan ste bob
t1  0   2   0
t2  2   0   1
t3  2   1   0
t4  1   0   2
t5  0   1   2
```

Column heading become index and sum product is the value:

```
    dan ste bob
dan 9   2   4
ste 2   6   2
bob 4   2   9
```

dan x dan = 9  (0*0)+(2*2)+(2*2)+(1*1)+(0*0)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: idk. i think you just use the `DataFrame.dot()` method to do matrix multiplication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`dot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) with its transpose:

```
In [11]: df.T.dot(df)
Out[11]:
     dan  ste  bob
dan    9    2    4
ste    2    6    2
bob    4    2    9
```

Answer (score 0):

You should using `.dot` this is just for fun

```
df1=pd.DataFrame(index=df.columns,columns=df.columns)
df1.apply(lambda x : [sum(df[x.name]*df[y]) for y in x.index])
Out[65]: 
     dan  ste  bob
dan    9    2    4
ste    2    6    2
bob    4    2    9
```